# How to refresh cache in Excel Power Query editor forcefully

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am pulling data through API from the web and creating few tables with transformations.

```
= Csv.Document(Web.Contents("Source"),[Delimiter=";", Encoding=1251, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])
```

When I spot the mistake in the middle of the steps i.e. add missing calculated column the all query start to crash and say I don't have column in the source even though it is there.
[There is such a column as Id MA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8S21.png)
Error when creating blank import:
[Error when pulling data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HS8Ui.png)
When I am trying to pull data from the source it gives error. When I am going to query options and clearing cache and push refresh all - everything start working until I add any step again.
As I understood, Power Query for some reason holds the table in the cache without data with error that no data received and don't update that preview. Clearing cash helps to see the data but it still thinks that there are no data in the source.

Does someone stack with the same situation?

I have tried clearing cache but it helps only for few minutes, when add new step the query crushes again
The column structure on all steps
[Column structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rtyv.png)

Comment: Could you add to your post a representative example query and perhaps a couple of images that shows the problem?

Comment: I have added few screenshots and the code for pulling data

Comment: Consider adding a timeout on the API call to ensure you're retrieving the data from the API fully before continuing with the other steps. I made a document that explains some time ago. You could also try using Web.BrowserContents instead of Web.Contents. See page 6 of this document for details of how to use timeout: https://github.com/ncalm/social_content/blob/master/Power%20Query/Owen%20Price%20-%20Power%20Query%20(M)%20-%20Exploring%20Web.BrowserContents%20and%20Html.Table.pdf

Comment: timeout hasn't helped. Regarding Web.BrowserContents Query says there is no such function. But I receive excel/csv file so I suppose this function won't help me